# Will AsEnumerable increase efficiency in this example?

Tags: performance, linq

In the following code:

```
    private bool IsValid()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            User.GetProfileAttributeByName("1"), 
            User.GetProfileAttributeByName("2"),
            User.GetProfileAttributeByName("3"),
            User.GetProfileAttributeByName("4")
        }.All(c => c != null);
    }
```

What I think happens is the array is fully materialized, calling `User.GetProfileAttributeByName` 4 times, then the All short circuits the first time it encounters `null`.

Would the following:

```
    private bool IsValid()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            User.GetProfileAttributeByName("1"), 
            User.GetProfileAttributeByName("2"),
            User.GetProfileAttributeByName("3"),
            User.GetProfileAttributeByName("4")
        }.AsEnumerable().All(c => c != null);
    }
```

Cause `All` to evaluate one element at a time or will the array still be fully materialized first?

(I realize this is moot if I just use && and a vanilla expression - I'm just trying to fully understand this example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will not make any difference - the array initialization will not be evaluated lazily, and using `AsEnumerable` will not change that.

You *could* evaluate it lazily by changing your query to:

```
    return new[]
    {
        "1", 
        "2",
        "3",
        "4"
    }.Select(s => User.GetProfileAttributeByName(s))
     .All(c => c != null);
```

Then the `Select` *will* be evaluated lazily and `All` *will* short-circuit.

or just

```
    return new[]
    {
        "1", 
        "2",
        "3",
        "4"
    }.All(s => User.GetProfileAttributeByName(s) != null);
```

Comment: You could also use `Lazy<>`, which pretty much exists for this purpose.

Comment: you can even shave it down to a method group on the Select (is "method group" the right term there?  I think I'm inferring that from something but I'm not positive I'm right....

Comment: True - you could combine the projection and the null check.  I've added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The array is already `Enumerable`. This wont make any difference.